# TypeScript: Select element of an array by type property

Tags: typescript, xml2js

In a TypeScript project, I have an array of containers that carry a `type` property and some additional data, depending on their type.

```
type Container<Type extends string> = {
    type: Type;
}

type AContainer = Container<"a"> & {
    dataA: number;
}

type BContainer = Container<"b"> & {
    dataB: boolean;
}

const data: (AContainer | BContainer)[] = [
    { type: "a", dataA: 17 },
    { type: "b", dataB: true }
];
```

My goal is to write a function that allows me to select an element from that array by its `type`, with full type safety. Something like this:

```
const getByType = <T extends string>(data: Container<string>[], type: T): Container<T> => {
    for (const c of data) {
        if (c.type === type) return c;
    }
    throw new Error(`No element of type ${type} found.`);
};

const dataA: AContainer = getByType(data, "a");
```

The problem is trying to convince TypeScript that the function is type-safe, and the return value is an element of the original array and has the requested type.

Here's my best attempt:

```
const getByType = <ContainerType extends Container<string>, Type extends string>(data: (ContainerType & Container<string>)[], type: Type): ContainerType & Container<Type> => {
    for (const c of data) {
        if (c.type === type) return c;
    }
    throw new Error(`No element of type ${type} found.`);
};
```

However, TypeScript neither understands that the comparison `c.type === type` ensures a `Container<string>` turns into a `Container<Type>`, nor that the return type of an example call, `AContainer | (Container<"b"> & { dataB: boolean; } & Container<"a">)`, is equal to `AContainer` because of the conflict in `Container<"b"> & Container<"a">`.
The first problem can be solved by using a type predicate as the one in the following code block (although that kind of feels like cheating), but I have not found a solution for the second problem.

```
const isContainer = <Type extends string>(c: Container<string>, type: Type): c is Container<Type> => {
    return typeof c === "object" && c.type === type;
};
```

Is there any way to get this to work? I'd prefer it if both `getByType` itself and its use were type-safe, but if that's not possible, I want at least the usage of `getByType` to not require any unsafe type assertions.

I can change the definitions of the container types, but the actual data is fixed. (For background: [xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) XML parser.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `infer` and `Extract` in order to achieve the goal. Consider:

```
const getByType = <ContainerType extends Container<string>, Type extends ContainerType extends Container<infer T> ? T : never, Chosen extends Type>(data: ContainerType[], type: Chosen) => {
    for (const c of data) {
        if (c.type === type) return c as Extract<ContainerType, {type: Chosen}>;
    }
    throw new Error(`No element of type ${type} found.`);
};

const containerA: AContainer = {
  dataA: 1,
  type: "a"
} 
const containerB: BContainer = {
  dataB: true,
  type: "b"
}
const b = getByType([containerB, containerA], 'b')
// b is infered as BContainer
```

Few things to pay attention:

- `type: ContainerType extends Container<infer T> ? T : never` We say argument needs to contain exact available type in the given array
- `Extract<ContainerType, {type: Chosen}>` we say we return element of the union with `{type: Chosen}` and it means the member with this exact type

We have here also strict type over second argument, in the example is narrowed to `a | b`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=34&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2AQwJYIgJwDwBVzQQAewECAJgM5SXCboDmAfFALxQDeAUFL1KJABcUfJADcXAL5cuA6AEF4SNBkxtYiFOizYARMl0sAZJx59yyFPOEIArgFsARlgnTZBKACElW1ep8qOrqOhlAm3HxQFiiewo5wcAA2EMgIrjIAxoi0UZbIwgAUipqBagA%20XgHamACUANoAuup1Zrwc-ATC%20roANLlWwgCMAOxQkj2tnB1CUMG9-cix-Ji20NINElxZCDkMEMCeIKLQ7NhVqsdQxKQU1Oc6tPQIzH2X12RUGsrVbyQfdyVqth0AAzLAiFgAfhEUBsEAAblg%20jAABZwShkK5-W4iAhMArRfJfXxYY6NPpyYSo9FkGpsFgRPgguBqArbHIZKBwEELOmMyK8VA8tkAOjkbFY7DkdMw%201smAQUE5yGoAFESJhkBlgGdARcCH0OJTYGiMQhJEwJJFpJFgCjMHAAO5QDDO1WYB2YAoAAwAcnArsl7GRgFyeeKACRGgiSKDM2wUEXemquTbs0PbEmYaxQYrfPzsRmEnODCa8Y3dKRQLbZDN6rBLbz1tSFsyEpZ0VZl6YQLohKQ1nahxzqPYHI4EAp1TOlTx9GfVeQNPoAckcK5qXCAA)

Comment: It looks like the return value of `getByType` has type `Container<"a" | "b">`, not `AContainer`, so I cannot access the `dataA` property afterwards.

Comment: The return type is now `Container<"a">`, which is better, but still not enough – it needs to be `AContainer` to allow me to access the `dataA` property.
(The crucial bit of information that allows this, in theory, is that `data` has type `(AContainer | BContainer)[]`, so it cannot contain an arbitrary container claiming to have type `a`, it truly needs to be an `AContainer`.)

Comment: Playing around with that a bit more, TypeScript normally does detect and eliminate empty union types. This may be a bug, which I reported [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36736).
I'd still be happy for a solution that works with current TypeScript, though.

Comment: The type is still inferred as `Container<"b">` for me, not `BContainer`. (Using TypeScript 3.7.5.)

Comment: Probably some copy/paste mistake I did, check the playground link I added

Comment: Indeed, `Extract` works! It requires the typecast within `getByType`, so I still hope TypeScript improves here, but this is _way_ better than anything I've found. **Thank you!**